# How to obtain information about DATABASES in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

Right now I'm working in MySQL, i want obtain information about databases.

f.e.

```
+-----------------+------------------------+
|  database_name  |  database_commentaries |
+-----------------+------------------------+
| example_db_name |   this is an example   |
+-----------------+------------------------+
```

Somebody knows how can i do this? Exists a query to obtain information about databases?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: See http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2036581&seqNum=7

Comment: try SELECT * FROM information_schema.schemata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing is [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/schemata-table.html).

But unlike TABLES, COLUMNS, STATISTICS, and PARTITIONS, SCHEMATA does not have a comments field.

Comment: Thank you, well, in mysql is a field "Comments about database" i thought that i can use this field.